# Writing 1 million records to an excel file

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

I am trying to write 1 million rows to and excel file using Java (I have to create an xls or xlsx).

Both Jxl and POI seem to be in-memory APIs, i.e both the apis will have the entire file of 1 million rows in the memory at a time.
This will end up in consuming Java heap space.
How can I read the records into the excel file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excel is not designed for this case. You should export them to CSV-File. There is no such limitation.

Answer (score 3):

apache-poi has a [streaming api](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) and can work with large data. I have used it till 500k. It may work for you with a million.

Comment: Note: The POI streaming API is write-only.

Answer (score 1):

JExcel can write excel files with help of temporary files instead of storing all the data in memory. You can enable it with following code:

```
WorkbookSettings settings = new WorkbookSettings();
settings.setGCDisabled( true );
settings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite( true );   
settings.setTemporaryFileDuringWriteDirectory(tmpDir);
Workbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(os, settings);
```